# Sinatra /w Thin: Logging?

Tags: sinatra, thin, webrick

I recently installed Thin for a Sinatra app I'm developing. However, it does not seem to be logging/outputing request, response and error messages a la WEBrick. Is there any way to turn these on, and to also use a debugging logger?

If not, I will happily switch back to WEBrick if someone can point out to me how to make Sinatra choose WEBrick over Thin (I'm using shotgun to run my sinatra app)

Comment: Logging can be achieved using middleware such as Rack::CommonLogger. But I am doubtful whether I understand that part of the question or not. Logging to the console in rails-style or logging to a file? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Logging to the console. Would using Rack::CommonLogger facilitate this? And, if so, how would I go about using it?

Comment: Not sure about the details on Rack::CommonLogger but you can use `Thin::Logging#log` method to log data to console similar to that of `console.log()` in firebug(JS) if you're familiar to that. This will work if your server is thin.

Comment: If using WEBrick, logging to console can be achieved via `logger=WEBrick::Log.new` `logger.log(1, "Logging to console just like firebug")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use WEBrick,  run shotgun as:
    shotgun yourapp.rb --server=webrick